# Resource Versioning in Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring-mvc

Can any one help me to  achieve Resource Versioning in my web application 
my dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.safecare" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="Messages" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_siz">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.safecare"></property>
    </bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/cortex_mcss_test1"
              p:username="root" p:password="mysql" />
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/JasperReport-View.xml" p:order="0" />
</beans>
```

and I did add the below code in the above xml and it create an error

> columnNumber: 18; cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'mvc:resources' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/">
<mvc:cache-control max-age="3600" s-maxage="1800" cache-public="true"/>
<mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="false" auto-registration="false">
    <mvc:resolvers>
        <mvc:version-resolver>
            <mvc:fixed-version-strategy version="abc" patterns="/**/*.js"/>
            <mvc:version-strategy patterns="/**">
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ContentVersionStrategy" />
            </mvc:version-strategy>
        </mvc:version-resolver>
        <ref bean="encodedResourceResolver"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver"/>
    </mvc:resolvers>
    <mvc:transformers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.CachingResourceTransformer">
            <constructor-arg name="cache" ref="resourceCache" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.AppCacheManifestTransformer"/>
    </mvc:transformers>
</mvc:resource-chain>
```

any one know any proper document for the above

Answer (score 0):

Add the self closing tag.

Change

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/">
```

to

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/" />
```